# Detecting a region of patch of color in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner to image analysis and am trying to write a program that does the
following-
What I have is the image of a heat map. Something that looks like:

[image: heat map]

What I need to do is for the program to detect if there is any region of 'problem'. In this case red would be considered problem. I went through tutorials and know how to detect if the color of region of problem is already known. I need to the program to tell me if there is a problem even if the two colors(red and green) is swamped. In that case, the problem would be green. So basically, if there is a patch of a color anywhere within a larger region of a different color, the program should draw a contour around the inner region. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

PS. I am using opencv 3 with python 2.7 running on raspbian jessie

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com , is strongly recommended to see the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to do good questions.

Comment: You can analyze the different color channels in the LAB color space. LAB isolates dominant colors in images pretty easily. Since green and red colors of your choice give LAB space a try